# Conditional lines on ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ion item and i want to display the lines according to a condition like this

```
<ion-item  *ngIf="type == group" lines="type != group"> </ion-item>
```

it's actually not displaying the lines

Comment: try binding the lines input to a expression with: `[lines]="type != 'group'"`.
btw I don't know if a boolean value is a correct value for the lines input.
I think it should be one of these values: `"full" | "inset" | "none" | undefined`. see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

Comment: do as @ChrisY explained. something like: `[lines]="type != 'group' ? 'none' : 'full'"`